# Where in the Spring Batch flow should I index an item?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, cassandra, spring-batch

I'm reading items from multiple flat files, processing them with some data validation steps, and writing them to Cassandra.  Somewhere in the flow, I need to also send an index request to ElasticSearch.  I'd like to use the ES Bulk API, so the index step should be batched to some degree.

My question is, should the Index step be an ItemProcessor, and ItemWriter, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the bulk indexing in an ItemWriter because it receives all the items of the chunk in one call. So you'll be able to bulk index all items in one operation. [This example](https://github.com/obazoud/spring-batch-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bazoud/batch/elasticsearch/writer/ElasticseachItemWriter.java) is a bit complicated but the`write` method will show you the idea. Alternative you can look in [Spring Batch Extensions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/blob/master/spring-batch-elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/data/ElasticsearchItemWriter.java)

I could do the same with Cassandra using an [unlogged batches](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html)

Finally you can wrap multiple ItemWriters (Cassandra and Elasticsearch) in one using [CompositeItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html)

Comment: give a look to ChunkListener

Comment: ChunkListener looks interesting, any examples of how to use it for this?  examples of it's use seem few.